# Running a process to execute maven install in Linux bash

Tags: java, linux, process

I have a POM file under /opt which I want to use to run mvn clean install. But this has to be done from a Sprinboot JAVA application running on a Linux server.

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","mvn clean install /opt"});

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "/opt". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or
:[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean,
validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes,
generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes,
test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site,
site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

Comment: It’s interpreting `/opt` as an argument to `mvn`, which doesn’t know what to do with it. It isn’t clear what you expect it to do.

Comment: I have a POM file under /opt which I want to use to run mvn clean install.

But this has to be done from a Sprinboot JAVA application running on a Linux server.

Comment: Done I have updated

Comment: So you might want to use one of the variants of `Runtime.exec` allowing /opt as working directory. However, running a Maven build in /opt from a running Spring Boot application sounds VERY strange to me...

Comment: @GyroGearless Basically its kind of running an application within another application.